# relational algebra specific operations

Tags: relational-algebra

I have these tables

```
Employee(ssn, name, sex, address, salary, bdate, dno, superssn)
fk:superssn is ssn in Employee
fk:dno is dnumber in Department

Department(dnumber, dname, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)
fk:mgrssn is ssn in Employee

Dept_locations(dnumber, dlocation)
fk:dnumber is dnumber in Department

Project(pnumber, pname, plocation, dnum)
fk:dnum is dnumber in Department

Dependent(essn, dependent_name, sex, bdate, relationship)
fk: essn is ssn in Employee

Works_on(essn,pno,hours)
fk: essn is ssn in Employee; pno is pnumber in Project
```

I would like to retrieve the list of locations for the finance department using only the following relational algebra operations {σ, π, ∪, ρ, −, ×}.

so far i have:
π dlocation (σ department (dname = 'research'))

i'm really stuck, and confused... i don't know if its possible to do it without an equijoin operation.

Answer (score 0):

Started writing a comment then changed my mind. :)

If you look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#.CE.B8-join_and_equijoin), you will find this equivalence:

```
R ⋈_φ S = σ_φ(R × S)
```

And particularly where the restriction is that of equality, it's an equijoin. What this means is, equijoin is equivalent to a restriction on a cartesian product of two tables on the equality of two fields.

So...

```
π_{dlocation}(
  σ_{dnumber = loc_dnumber}(
    σ_{dname = "finance"}(department)
    ×
    ρ_{loc_dnumber / dnumber}(dept_locations)))
```

(We need to use a rename so that we don't get into the nonsensical `dnumber = dnumber` place.)